# Finding factorial with C

Tags: c, factorial

just a newbie in C here. I'm trying to print out the factorial given the input using recursion & pointers, but when my input is 5, the output was 2293620. Can somebody help me with this? I'm not sure where did that number come from, because factorial of 5 should give me 120. Thanks for your help!

```
#include<stdio.h>


int countlength(int *num) {
    
    int x = 1;
    if (*num == 1) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return *num * countlength(num-1);
    }
}

int main() {

    int n, l;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    l = countlength(&n);
    printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n", n, l);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `countlength(num-1)` Compiler should give you a warning there. That is subtracting from a pointer and not the value referenced by the pointer. Suggest you change the function to take a `int` parameter rather than an `int *`. There's no need to pass as a pointer and it will make your life easier.

Comment: Why do you pass a pointer as the argument to `countlength`?

Comment: Always enable your compiler's warnings! (e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` with gcc/clang) It would have found the issue.

Comment: Please read the diagnostics. They're given for a reason.

Answer (score 1):

Remove references from your code.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int countlength(int num) {
    
    int x = 1;
    if (num == 1) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return num * countlength(num-1);
    }
}

int main() {

    int n, l;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    l = countlength(n);
    printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n", n, l);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think you don't need to use pass by reference. You should use pass by value. Then your code will work perfectlyly

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
return num * countlength(num - 1);
```

to this:

```
int val = *num - 1;
return *num * countlength(&val);
```

So you correctly assign the value and pass it as a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

````
int countlength(int *num) {
    
    int x = *num - 1;
    if (*num == 1) {
        return 1; 
    } else {
        return *num * countlength(&x);
    }
}

int main() {

    int n, l;
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    l = countlength(&n);
    printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n", n, l);
    return 0;
}```
**Try this**
````

Comment: [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66610102/11471113) also explained the same thing. What's different?

Answer (score -3):

int countlength(int *num) {

```
if (*num == 1) {
    return 1; 
} else {
    return *num * countlength(&(*num - 1));
}
```

}

int main() {

```
int n, l;
printf("Enter number: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
l = countlength(&n);
printf("The factorial of %d is %d\n", n, l);
return 0;
```

}

try this

Comment: It's always good to add some text explaining how your code solves the OP's problem.